# What is the verb form of "Cheque" or "Bank Check"?

Tags: verbs, nouns, sentence

I am writing a corporate policy about transactions that needs written checks. Is there a shorter for it like, "Transactions for chequeing (checking)? So it doesn't sound like checking (correcting).

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul  I don’t see an answer there. I would use “cheque transactions.

Comment: Try “Check Transactions”

Comment: This is basically a single word request: You need to put the word into a sentence, not a phrase. As your example stands at the moment it is probably a gerund.

Comment: I don't think there's a verb that fits there. An appropriate phrase might be "Transactions by check".